# Create a PDF with specific page ranges of multiple PDF files?

Tags: pdf, merge, pdftk

I have found many related questions in this forum. But, none addresses my issue. Please double-check before marking it as duplicate.

Suppose I have two PDF files.

1. `first.pdf` having 10 pages.
2. `second.pdf` having 20 pages.

I want to create a new PDF file, where I need pages - 2,5,6,9 from `first.pdf` and pages 6,7,15,19 from `second.pdf`.

How to do it from command line?

Comment: And what would be the sequence of the pages? I mean you want first all the pages extracted from first.pdf, and consequently the pages extracted from second.pdf? 

Or maybe you want from both pdfs pages 2,5,6,6,7,9,15,19

Comment: @lese I don't want to extract all the pages from `first.pdf`. I want a new PDF file, which would have total eight pages, having four pages (2,5,6,9) of `first.pdf` and four pages (6,7,15,19) from `second.pdf`.

Answer (score 21):

You can use `pdfseparate` command to split all pages of pdfs into single page pdf. The following command will create `last_page`-`first_page` pdfs where their name will be `out_<pageNumber>`:

```
pdfseparate -f <first_page> -l <last_page> <file_name>.pdf out_%d.pdf
```

Apply the process to both pdf using different output name for each input pdf, so you don't overwrite previously created single page pdfs. Then you can use `pdfunite` for merging selected pages into a single one pdf:

```
pdfunite <ordered list of pdf> <output_filename>.pdf
```

Comment: I had this error: 

```Unimplemented Feature: Could not merge encrypted files. ```

Was solved using an intermediate command: 

```qpdf --decrypt <source.pdf> <unencrypted.pdf>```

Thanks @Danibix

Comment: Thank you, it works fine.

Answer (score 18):

You can use **pdftk**

in just **ONE** step:

```
pdftk A=first.pdf B=second.pdf cat A2 A5 A6 A9 B6 B7 B15 B19 output final.pdf
```

PS. If you need to install, you should:

```
sudo apt-get install pdftk
```

Answer (score 2):

Install `pdftk`:

```
sudo apt install pdftk
```

then, to extract "2 5 6 9" from first one in a file named "1.pdf":

```
pdftk first.pdf cat 2 5 6 9 output 1.pdf
```

and for the second.pdf:

```
pdftk second.pdf cat  6 7 15 19 output 2.pdf
```

Then merge them:

```
pdftk 1.pdf 2.pdf output final.pdf
```

And remove unnecessary ones:

```
rm 1.pdf 2.pdf
```

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that pdftk is not included in bionic (Ubuntu 18.04). Is there an alternative to pdftk available? I have not found it yet.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=pdftk

Comment: Update: it seems that pdfseparate and pdfunite is just as good, it is found in the `poppler-utils` package. Upvoting the answer by @Danibix

Comment: Why is pdftk not included?

Answer (score 2):

As `pdftk` is no longer available in the repositories you could use `mutool` from `mupdf-tools` with a command like:

```
mutool merge -o output.pdf first.pdf 2,5,6,9 second.pdf 6,7,15,19
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple with qpdf (works also with Cygwin on Windows):

`qpdf --empty --pages 'file1.pdf' 1,2,4-10 'file2.pdf' 11-26 'file1.pdf' 27-29  -- ./merged-result.pdf`